# Expand/Collapse section tableview swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have 3 sections and their corresponding cells how to make it expand/collapse? I have created an struct having expanded:Bool value
below are my code.
*THIS IS MY cellForRowAt *

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    switch (indexPath.section) {
    case 0:
        if let cell1 = tableview.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TimeCardDetailedTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as? TimeCardDetailedTableViewCell{
            
        return cell1
        }
    case 1:
        if let cell2 = tableview.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MessageDetailedTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as? MessageDetailedTableViewCell{
            
            
        return cell2
        }
    case 2:
        if let cell3 = tableview.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CrewDetailedTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as? CrewDetailedTableViewCell{
            
        return cell3
        }
    default:
        return UITableViewCell()
    }
    return UITableViewCell()
}
```

--->>this is **numberOfRowsInSection**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    switch (section) {
    case 0:
        return self.timecards.count
    case 1:
        return self.msglog.count
    default:
        return self.profile.count
    }
}
```

--->>> viewForHeaderInSection

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    if section == 0{
        let header1 = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("TimeCardHeaderTableViewCell", owner: self, options: nil)?.last as! TimeCardHeaderTableViewCell
        header1.backgroundColor = .red
        return header1
    } else if section == 1 {
        let header2 = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("MessageTableViewCell", owner: self, options: nil)?.last as! MessageTableViewCell
        return header2
    } else if section == 2 {
        let header3 = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("CrewTableViewCell", owner: self, options: nil)?.last as! CrewTableViewCell
        return header3
    }
    return UITableViewCell()
    
}
```

How to implement expansion on section.im new to iOS

Comment: Declare a model representing your cell model, which has a bool property to detect expand/collapse state. Then when tapped on cell, toggle that bool property and reload cell at index path

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to update your `numberOfRowsInSection` like this

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int { 
   switch (section) { 
     case 0: return self.hiddenSections.contains(0) ? 0 : self.timecards.count 
     case 1: return self.hiddenSections.contains(1) ? 0 : return self.msglog.count 
     case 2: return self.hiddenSections.contains(2) ? 0 : return self.profile.count 
   } 
}
```

viewForHeaderInSection will be like this, where you will set `tag` and `selector`.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        let sectionButton = UIButton()
        sectionButton.setTitle(String(section),
                               for: .normal)
        sectionButton.backgroundColor = .systemBlue
        sectionButton.tag = section
        sectionButton.addTarget(self,
                                action: #selector(self.hideSection(sender:)),
                                for: .touchUpInside)

        return sectionButton
    }
```

`hideSection` method will have logic to hide/show your section

```
@objc
    private func hideSection(sender: UIButton) {
        let section = sender.tag
        
        func indexPathsForSection() -> [IndexPath] {
            var indexPaths = [IndexPath]()
            
            for row in 0..<self.tableViewData[section].count {
                indexPaths.append(IndexPath(row: row,
                                            section: section))
            }
            
            return indexPaths
        }
        
        if self.hiddenSections.contains(section) {
            self.hiddenSections.remove(section)
            self.tableView.insertRows(at: indexPathsForSection(),
                                      with: .fade)
        } else {
            self.hiddenSections.insert(section)
            self.tableView.deleteRows(at: indexPathsForSection(),
                                      with: .fade)
        }
    }
```